# Adding sublists elements based on indexing by condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list like below

```
a=[['a',1,2,1,3],['b',1,3,4,3],['c',1,3,4,3]]
b=[['b',1,3,4,3],['c',1,3,4,3]]
```

I want add the elements based on index if 1st sublist element match with other list sublist element

tried with below:

```
from operator import add 

res_list1=[]
    for a1 in a:
        for b1 in b:
            if a1[0]==b1[0]:
                res_list = [map(add, a1[1:], b1[1:])]
                res = [[a1[0],i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in res_list]
                res_list1.append(res[0])
            else:
                res_list=a1
                res_list1.append(res_list)

    print res_list1
```

but output resulting like below:

```
res_list1=[['a', 1, 2, 1, 3], ['a', 1, 2, 1, 3], ['b', 2, 6, 8, 6], ['b', 1, 3, 4, 3], ['c', 1, 3, 4, 3], ['c', 2, 6, 8, 6]]
```

but correct output should be:

```
res_list1=[['a', 1, 2, 1, 3], ['b', 2, 6, 8, 6], ['c', 2, 6, 8, 6]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) based approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, islice

l = sorted(a+b)
[[k] + [sum(i) for i in islice(zip(*v),1,None)] for k,v in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0))]
# [['a', 1, 2, 1, 3], ['b', 2, 6, 8, 6], ['c', 2, 6, 8, 6]]
```

Comment: This is the most complete solution wrt to flexibility for cases in which there are multiple sub-lists with same first index item like if `a=[['a',8,2,1,1],['b',1,1,3,3],['c',1,3,8,3]]` and `b=[['b',2,7,9,0],['c',2,8,1,4], ['a', 7,3,0,5], ['b', 6,5,0,8]]`, output will be `[['a', 15, 5, 1, 6], ['b', 9, 13, 12, 11], ['c', 3, 11, 9, 7]]`.

Comment: @yatu: Thanks. it help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function like this one:

```
def add_elements(a, b):
    b_dict = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in b}
    default = [0 for _ in a][:-1]
    return [i[:1] + [sum(x) for x in zip(i[1:], b_dict.get(i[0], default))] for i in a]
```

And call it with your lists as arguments:

```
add_elements(a, b)
#[['a', 1, 2, 1, 3], ['b', 2, 6, 8, 6], ['c', 2, 6, 8, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

see @zipa's answer for a more Pythonic (efficient, short, readable, overall better) solution using dictionaries.

I will try to answer using the original structure of your own code:

```py
from operator import add

a=[['a',1,2,1,3],['b',1,3,4,3],['c',1,3,4,3]]
b=[['b',1,3,4,3],['c',1,3,4,3]]

res_list1=[]
for a1 in a:
    found_match = False
    for b1 in b:
        if a1[0]==b1[0]:
            found_match = True
            res_list = [map(add, a1[1:], b1[1:])]
            res = [[a1[0],i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in res_list]
            res_list1.append(res[0])
    if not found_match:
        res_list = a1
        res_list1.append(res_list)

print(res_list1)
```

The problem you had is always appending to `res_list1`, every iteration of the inner loop (so for every `(a1,b1)` pair).
what I did to solve this is "remember" (that is - keep in a boolean variable) whether we found a match for `a1` in `b`, and only if not - add the original list to the result

Comment: @adam-er8 +1 for easy to understand solution for intermediate python practitioners.. However, this line is not clear `res = [[a1[0],i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in res_list]`. Can you elaborate on it. thanks.

Comment: @mnm I took from the original snippet in the question, what it does is just prepend the common letter to the elements after adding them. There are much cleaner ways to do this (e.g. `[a1[0]] + res_list`), but I wanted to give the OP an answer with minimal changes